# ProgressDialog setCancelable(false) in XML

Tags: android, xml, progressdialog

Is there any possibility to setCancelable(false) on ProgressDialog but not in code? I want to add this property to style. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Set `android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside` to value `false`.